# RestKit responseDescriptor mapping without KVC

Tags: ios, ios7, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am trying to map this response from API url (...com/api/login?params...)

```
{"success":0,"error":"Some error"}
```

But I can't get it working. I have this class:

```
@interface LoginResponse : NSObject

@property(nonatomic) NSNumber * Success;
@property(nonatomic) NSString * Error;

@end
```

This I have in my AppDelegate.m (with other working response descriptors):

```
RKObjectMapping *loginMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[LoginResponse class]];
[loginMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                   @"success" : @"Success",
                                                   @"error" : @"Error",
                                                  }];

RKResponseDescriptor *loginResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:loginMapping
                                                                                             method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                        pathPattern:@"/login"
                                                                                            keyPath:nil
                                                                                        statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[manager addResponseDescriptor:loginResponseDescriptor];
```

And I am calling it like this:

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

[manager getObjectsAtPath:@"/api/login"
               parameters:@{@"nickname":@"...",@"password":@"test"}
                  success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
 {
     NSArray* statuses = [mappingResult array];

 }
                  failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                     message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                    delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [alert show];
     NSLog(@"Hit error: %@", error);
 }];
```

And I get these errors:

```
Hit error: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 "No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched." UserInfo=0x10a2b48d0 {NSLocalizedDescription=No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched., NSLocalizedFailureReason=The mapping operation was unable to find any nested object representations at the key paths searched: events, points, results
The representation inputted to the mapper was found to contain nested object representations at the following key paths: error, success
This likely indicates that you have misconfigured the key paths for your mappings., keyPath=null, DetailedErrors=(
)}
```

I just can't get it working. I am trying to look at wiki for RestKit but I think I have it okay. Just few changes to my case but I guess it should be working. What I have wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is path patterns in relation to your base URL. They currently don't match.

I would set the bast URL to: `...com/api/`. Then both the response descriptor path pattern and the get objects path are `login`. Now everything matches.

If the base URL is set to `...com`, then the path patterns will *both* need to be `/api/login`.

Comment: I was trying "api/login" before but it didn't work. But now I tried "/api/login" and it works. Thanks

Comment: I usually set the base URL as long as possible and include the trailing slash so it isn't required in path patterns everywhere.

Comment: So you think it's better to use base url as `http://www...com/api/` when I am always using `/api/` and removed it from `pathPatterns` and `getObjectsAtPath`?

Comment: Personally, yes, but it is entirely personal preference. So long as everything matches they are functionally equivalent.